# It will not compile and gives the "Selection cannot be launched and there are no recent launches” error.

Tags: c++, eclipse

[image: error] 
I tried to build and run "Hello world" with Eclipse and it wont run. I don't use Android or anything else just plain C++.

http://i57.tinypic.com/x51h5h.png

Comment: Could you mark my answer as the solution please?

Answer (score 3):

So I've had this issue a bunch of times before. This is what worked for me:

Go to the Projects tab at the top, then
Properties>C/C++ Build>Settings, click on Binary parsers tab and select "PE Windows Parser" and then click on Error Parsers tab and select "Microsoft Visual C error parser"

All that for good measure. Now, click apply and then right click on your project and "Build". Then click on the play button on top which would run your application and it should run.

1 more thing: When you add your test.cpp file:
Right click on the project folder, New>Source File and then add test.cpp in the Source file edit box.
That should do it!

Comment: thanks it works, but what did you mean by : "more thing: When you add your test.cpp file: Right click on the project folder, New>Source File and then add test.cpp in the Source file edit box. That should do it!". Why should i add test.cpp I already have tester.cpp which contains main()?

Comment: I saw that your test.cpp file was in a seperate folder called "src". Sometimes this doesn't compile properly because the include files are in a different directory. But if it compiles then don't worry about all that.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, follow these steps:

1. Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Launching`
2. In `Launching -> Launch Operation` select "Launch the associated project". For help, keep the options as the image below:

[image]

3. Select "Run as Local C/C++ application"